# 'Got Object' exception in GraphQL schema definition

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

The schema that I defined is like so:

```
import { gql } from 'apollo-server';

export default gql`
    type ProjectEntry {
        ID: Int!
        Name: String
    }

    # The schema allows the following Queries:
    type Query {
        project(id: Int!): ProjectEntry
        projects: [ProjectEntry]
    }
`;
```

At the end I bring it all together with:

```
const typeDefs = require('./data/typedefs');
const resolvers = require('./data/resolvers ');

const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });
```

But when I try to run the application, I get this error: `Error: typeDef array must contain only strings and functions, got object`

Where is this error coming from?

Comment: How are you importing your typeDefs?

Comment: @DanielRearden, I've updated the post with the info you asked for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `export default 'someString'`, under the hood, the resulting value for `exports` value ends up being `{ default: 'someString' }`. That's what allows you do declare both a default export and named exports. Import your module

```
// like this
const typeDefs = require('./data/typedefs').default

// or like this
import typedefs from './data/typedefs'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same error.
Solution:

```
const { typeDefs } = require('./data/typedefs');
const { resolvers } = require('./data/resolvers ');
```

parentheses needed because we don't export default value.
As on frontend:

```
export default Component -> import Component from "..."
export const Component -> import { Component } from "..."
```